# H2 ManyToMany populate

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I want to poulate ManyToMany table in my H2 database for test.  I have Entities with many to many relationship. I know how to insert table "sessions" and table "speakers", but i dont know how to insert table "session_speakers":

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sessions")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Session {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "session_id")
    private Long sessionId;

    @Column(name = "session_name")
    private String sessionName;

    @Column(name = "session_description")
    private String sessionDescription;

    @Column(name = "session_length")
    private Integer sessionLength;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "session_speakers",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "session_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "speaker_id"))
    private List<Speaker> speakers;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "speakers")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Speaker {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "speaker_id")
    private Long speakerId;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "company")
    private String company;

    @Column(name = "speaker_bio")
    private String speakerBio;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "speakers")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Session> sessions;
```

My H2JpaConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class H2JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .setName("DataBaseTestConfig" + ZonedDateTime.now() + UUID.randomUUID()).build();
    }
}
```

my application-h2.properties:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create\r\n
spring.jpa.database=h2
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=password
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc\:h2\:mem\:testdb;;
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

and my data.sql for tests:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (session_name,session_length,session_description)
VALUES ('Keynote - The Golden Age of Software',45,''),
       ('A Better Way to Access Data with Spring Data',60,''),
       ('A Deep Dive Into Spring IoC',60,'') ...


INSERT INTO speakers (first_name,last_name,title,company,speaker_bio)
VALUES ('Sergio','Becker','Senior Developer','MicroOcean Software','Test'),
       ('James','Lowrey','Solutions Architect','Fabrikam Industries','Test') ...


INSERT INTO session_speakers (session_id,speaker_id)
VALUES (1,40),
       (2,4),
       (3,5)...
```

when i run my tests i got error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #6 of URL [file:/C:/work/JIRA_work/nauka/spring_project/ps-spring-data-jpa/conference-demo/target/test-classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO session_speakers (session_id,speaker_id) VALUES (1,40), (2,4), ...  nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKBSD81C224TLAEPMSBQIWO3OBG: PUBLIC.SESSION_SPEAKERS FOREIGN KEY(SESSION_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SESSIONS(SESSION_ID) (82)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO session_speakers (session_id,speaker_id) VALUES (1,40), (2,4) ...
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at
```

I would like to know, how to properly populate ManyToMany table.

Comment: what is your id 1, 40, 2, 4, 5 in your file data.sql ? I think you're doing fine, juste reference the ID yourself, otherwise, the foreign key might not be found in the target table

Comment: well, quick solution would be to add id's to your "sessions" and "speakers" insert clauses, so that the values you use in third INSERT will actually make sense. but I am not sure if that should be THE right approach - I normally work w/some proper migration tool, like Liquibase or Flyway, not with this ... approach. Also if those data are strictly for tests, why not insert them in the test code?

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing non-existent IDs.

You should either insert IDs manually (not relying on them being generated by the database) in the first two tables and reference those later.

```
INSERT INTO sessions (speaker_id, session_name,session_length,session_description)
VALUES (1, 'Keynote - The Golden Age of Software',45,''),
       (2, 'A Better Way to Access Data with Spring Data',60,''),
       (3, 'A Deep Dive Into Spring IoC',60,'') ...

INSERT INTO speakers (session_id, first_name,last_name,title,company,speaker_bio)
VALUES (11, 'Sergio','Becker','Senior Developer','MicroOcean Software','Test'),
       (12, 'James','Lowrey','Solutions Architect','Fabrikam Industries','Test') ...

INSERT INTO session_speakers (session_id,speaker_id)
VALUES (1,11),
       (2,12),
       (3,11)...
```

Or you can populate the first two tables the way you do it now, but than you have to find the correct IDs when inserting into the junction table.

```
INSERT INTO session_speakers (session_id,speaker_id)
VALUES (
  (SELECT session_id FROM sessions WHERE session_name = 'Keynote - The Golden Age of Software'),
  (SELECT speaker_id FROM speakers WHERE last_name = 'Becker'))...
```

This way may not be the right one in your situation, but there are circumstances where it can be appropriate.